# Vim --remote-silent always opens [No Name] buffer for first file

Tags: vim

I want to be able to open files using the same instance so I added `--remote-silent` when opening files. But the first time it loads, Vim will open an empty buffer, then my file. So now I have 2 buffers.

Upon further investigation, I noticed that setting `nohidden` will solve this problem. BUT, not only is it against my liking, it will cause the first buffer to have no syntax highlighting.

This doesn't happen without the `--remote-silent` option.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Doing `$ vim --servername FOO --remote[-silent] filename` without an instance already running launches a new instance first *then* opens the file: it is not like `$vim filename`. You have to find a way to completely remove the first empty buffer.

From my limited testing, adding `set bufhidden=wipe` to your `~/.vimrc` may solve the problem.

`set bufhidden=wipe`, being local to a buffer, is applied only to the first empty buffer and reset afterwards.

See `:h bufhidden`.

This will certainly cause some problems when you run Vim normally, though.

***edit***

Yes, `set bufhidden=wipe` causes obvious problems. When launched "normally" (with `$vim file1`) the first buffer is wiped when you edit a second file which is not what you want.

A simple check on the name of the buffer resolves that problem:

```
if bufname('%') == ''
  set bufhidden=wipe
endif
```

Syntax highlighting works in every situation, here. Could you post the content of your `~/.vim/` and `~/.vimrc` somewhere?

Comment: That succesfully deleted the buffer but the first file has no syntax highlighting. And I can't turn it on either.

Comment: The file is syntax highlighted, here. Anyway, bufhidden doesn't seem to be a valid solution because it will wipe `file1` when doing `:e file2` after launching `$ vim file1`. An `autocmd` should be preferable, I think.

Comment: My vimrc http://paste2.org/p/2203811 See line 57 for what I did to solve my problem. Not sure if this is the correct way, but it seems to work so far.

Comment: @Dalton Tan, what if you want to open a directory. E.g. `gvim --remote .` with the intention of the user selecting and opening a file. I use NerdTree and sadly your approach wipes NerdTree. Oh hum.

Answer (score 2):

The `--remote` family of options allows for an additional Ex command to be performed after opening the file.

What you can do here is add `:bd1` which deletes buffer #1 which is the [No Name] buffer.

example: `--remote-silent +:bd1 {file}`

Comment: Awesome: needs to be the accepted answer.  Solved an issue re: Vim as external editor for Claws Mail (bash script with `xfce4-terminal --disable-server --geometry=230x60+60+0 -x vim -f --remote-silent +:bd1 "$@"` called via `/mnt/Vancouver/programming/scripts/claws_mail-external_editor.sh %s` setting as external text editor command in Claws Mail. Issues solved were as per OP's issue, and the need to open a new instance of Vim for CM message compositions, when existing Vim with open buffers present.